# Hidden searchbar until the user wants to search

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var search = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        Text ("Hello World 1")
        Text ("Hello World 2" )
        Text ("Hello World 3")
      }
      .navigationTitle( "Menu" )
    }
    .searchable(text: $search,
                placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
  }
}
```

This code shows this view

[image]

The search bar is visible when the view appears.

What I want is what Apple does. The search bar is hidden when the view appears, and the list starts at the position `Hello World 1` is. Then, if the user scrolls down from there, the search bar shows.

From that point on, if the user scrolls up, the search bar goes away with elements of the list and returns if the user scrolls down all the way.

The Settings application works like this.

How do I do that for iOS 15.

Comment: Did you try using display mode ```.automatic``` instead of ```.always```?

Comment: yes, same thing. Always displayed when the list shows.

Comment: I have the same problem and could not find a solution. The difference between `.automatic` and `.always` is that with the later search bar will always be shown even when scrolling.